# Div bottom of div

Tags: html, css, division

```css
div.div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}
div.div2 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class = "div1">
  <div class = "div2">Test1</div>
  <div class = "div2">Test2</div>
</div>
```

I use the above code to make a big div contain two smallers. The first one should be on the top and the second on the bottom. The top part works good but for the second div I can't make it to be on the bottom of the bigger div... What should I use?

Comment: You want "test2" to be outside/underneath the bigger div (`.div1`)?

Comment: No just like `test1` is on top/touches the top part of the div, same with `test2` to be on the bottom (inside)

Comment: @darkchampionz for this to work u either use `position:absolute` as in the answer below or use `flexbox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the parent a flex `column` and use `justify-content: space-between` to separate the children.

```css
div.div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div.div2 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class = "div1">
  <div class = "div2">Test1</div>
  <div class = "div2">Test2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute;` on the second DIV, with `position: relative;` on the wrapper/parent and position settings as shown below.

```css
div.div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
div.div2 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
div.div2:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class = "div1">
  <div class = "div2">Test1</div>
  <div class = "div2">Test2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you really trying to achieve

you need to be able to always control your divs so make sure you always define them better

```
div.div1 {
 border: 1px solid red;
 height: 100px;
}
div.div2 {
 border: 1px solid yellow;
 width:100px; 
min-height: 10 px;
float:left;
}

<div class = "div1">
  <div class = "div2">Test1</div>
  <div class = "div2">Test2</div>
</div>
```

since your div one does not define its own space you dont know what the bottom is . so you can add clear property to make sure anything you put above div 2 is cleared.

Good luck